# Parse Rails timezone to_s on the JVM

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am writing a JVM based client for Shopify, and need to get the timezone info from the API. The data returned is of the form:

```
"(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

Which doesn't actually describe the timezone. The standard format for timezones is generally of the form:

```
"America/New_York"
```

and is described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). I am using [Joda-time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) to manage the timezones on the JVM side, and need to parse that string. The best I can do right now is to copy the list in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) into my code, strip the offset from the string and look it up. My problem with this is that the list looks rather incomplete and will be subject to change.

I rejected using the GMT-05:00 part since that fails to take into account DST and therefore doesn't describe the timezone, so it will be wrong for 6 months of the year, which is unacceptable.

Alternatively, it would be useful the Shopify API just provided the timezone, but I have searched the [docs](http://api.shopify.com/shop.html) and can't see where that is. If someone can see it and I'm just being dumb, that would be great.

P.S. I'm not a ruby programmer, so it's entirely possible I'm missing something really obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, but I was able to keep a copy of the Java compatible time zone identifier along with the Ruby/Rails one.  You will probably have to build a conversion table to convert "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" to "America/New_York".

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. I was trying to avoid having to maintain that massive lookup table. Ah well.

Comment: @l0st3d I don't know the architecture of your solution, but you could shell out to ruby to convert the time zone, instead of messing with jRuby or conversion table.

Comment: true, that is another option. I've gone for maintaining my own mappings as that fits my restrictions best. It would just be nice if people stuck to standards for this sort of thing ;P

Answer (score -1):

I have a similar product. On the Android side I use `TimeZone.getDefault().getId()`. It is generally already in the TZ database form you're asking for. On the ruby side I've found the [timezone gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/timezone) to be invaluable for scheduling, though I had to modify the gem a bit to meet my performance needs.

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood my question. I know how to turn "America/New_York" into a timezone. I don't know how to turn "(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)" into a timezone without running an instance of JRuby in my app, or maintaining my own list of mappings.

Comment: My point was that the API I provided should always give you timezones information in the format you wanted. I missed, however, that this is an Android API and you're targeting the JVM.